# PrimeNG toolbar button with dropdown appears in the wrong place

Tags: javascript, primeng, primeng-menu

I've made a stackblitz example here to show the issue:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-toolbar-demo-u21zmt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

When clicking the remove button the popup menu shows in the wrong place.

[image: demo]

I don't want to have to write custom CSS to position the menu every time I want to use it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Switch the order in your html so

```
    <p-button class="p-mr-2" #removeBtn type="button" icon="pi pi-chevron-down" label="Remove"
      (click)="removeMenu.toggle($event)"></p-button>
    <p-menu #removeMenu [model]="removeMenuItems" [popup]="true" appendTo="removeBtn"></p-menu>
```

becomes

```
    <p-menu #removeMenu [model]="removeMenuItems" [popup]="true" appendTo="removeBtn"></p-menu>
    <p-button class="p-mr-2" #removeBtn type="button" icon="pi pi-chevron-down" label="Remove"
      (click)="removeMenu.toggle($event)"></p-button>
```

This will make the menu appear under "remove"

Comment: I'm not sure if this is quite right, the menus now appear on top of the buttons. So whilst they're correctly aligned horizontally they're not aligned vertically. It's definitely an improvement.

Comment: also in primeng's stack blitz they put the menu under the button: 

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-menu-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html